# plot only out of bag error rate in random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

When I run random forest in R package and use plot function, there have many curves including out of bag error rate curve (black colour) and the misclassification error rate curves (other colours). However, I only would like to show on the plot only the out of bag error rate curve. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curves can be subsetted using the **$** symbol in R.

So, this is how you single out the error rate curve.

```
$err.rate
```

You might also want to look at the documentation of the random forest plot by: (`?plot.randomForest`)

Comment: How would you plot the `err.rate` then? `plot(someModel$err.rate)` does not do the trick

Answer (score 0):

More in detail:

Your `confusion Matrix` contains a variable, called `err.rate` which you access with the `$` sign.  The `err.rate` is stored as a matrix where the first column is the `OOB Error`. Each class gets its own column. Try `str(someModel$err.rate)`.

To access the `err.rate` do this `$err.rate[,1]`, for plotting simply `plot(myModel $err.rate[,1])`.
The other columns in your `matrix` are the error rates of your classes!